# Does every manifold M always admit a Riemannian metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, principal-bundles

In the book "*Geometry and Topology for Physicists*" by Nash and Sen, in Section 7.6, after showing that the structure group $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ of a frame bundle $F(M)$ (for a general manifold $M$ of dimension $n$) is reducible to $O(n)$, they write

> *[...] we have shown that every manifold $M$ always admits a Riemannian metric.*

1) I am a bit confused about the following proof, can anyone clarify it to me please ?

2) Moreover, I was thaught that one defines a manifold $M$ to be Riemannian if it admits a metric, i.e. if it has $O(n)$ as structure group.
I thought that in general manifold had $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ as structure group (and so not necessarily Riemannian), but the statement above seems to claim that every manifold is Riemannian (by always admitting a metric).
What did I get wrong?

Comment: It's like saying a topological space is metrizable versus saying it's a metric space. A manifold may admit more than one Riemannian metric. It becomes a Riemannian manifold when we pick one. Otherwise we don't have a particular Riemannian metric in mind, so it's just a manifold.

Comment: (Also, the manifold has to be differentiable for such a metric to exist, there are topological manifolds that have no differentiable structure.)

Comment: In the context of frame bundles, a Riemannian manifold is a manifold with a *choice* of reduction of the structure group to $O(n)$. The point of this is that you can always do so.

Comment: Ok, then I think I need to understand better the difference between the structure  group for the frame bundle $F(M)$ and the structure group for the tangent bundle $T(M)$. Both are (in general) $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ and then reducible to $O(n)$ as showed in that book. I thought that these were conceptually the same thing and that having a $O(n)$ structure for $T(M)$ meant that one has a globally defined metric.

Can you clarify this to me? thank you for your help

Comment: Ok, thank you, maybe I got it. In general the structure group $GL(n, R)$ may be reduced to some subgroup $H < G(n,R)$ (e.g. $O(n), U(n), ...$), but this means just that the manifold may admit some globally defined invariant (under $H$) tensor. When one "picks" this tensor (or show that it exists), the structure group becomes $H$, and one has a so-called "$H$-manifold".

Correct ?

Comment: @BLS: Your last parenthetical is not really right: showing that it exists does not make $M$ into a Riemannian manifold. Remember that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold with that *choice* of tensor, or *choice* of reduction; an almost complex manifold is one with a *choice* of reduction to $U(n)$/fiberwise almost complex structure; etc. But otherwise you have the right idea.

Comment: Ok, but in some notes given by a Professor of mine, I read:

''If there exists a globally defined non-degenerate $G$-invariant tensor or set of such tensors, than the manifold has a $G$-structure".

It proceeds by explaining that if one has a globally defined $G$-invariant tensor one can select a set of frames in which this tensor has the same form. Then follows that the only allowed transition functions are those keeping this form invariant, hence they belong to $G$. On the other hand, the converse is easier (given a $G$-manifold one can find some globally defined $G$-invariant tensor).

Comment: That's totally fine. I was just pointing out that knowing that there exists a $G$-structure (that is, knowing that there exists a reduction) is not the same thing as having a $G$-structure (having a reduction).

Comment: Alternatively you can show that every manifold admits a Riemannian metric by using the Whitney embedding theorem and then taking the pullback metric.

Answer (score 3):

2) You are wrong in that admitting a certain structure is not equivalent to having (fixed choice of) certain structure. In other words, for any smooth manifold $M$ there is a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, such that if you forget the metric $g$ on $M'$, you will get just $M$. The catch is that the pair $(M,g)$ is not unique.

As a silly example, take the sphere $S^2$. You can embed it into $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the unit sphere to get one (induced) metric on it, or as a cube (smoothed), and get another induced metric. But as smooth manifolds (forgetting the metric), those are the same.

As a more interesting example, take the flat torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ with the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the torus which is the surface of a doughnut, embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$. As smooth manifolds they are the same, but as Riemannian manifolds they differ; for example one can be (indeed *is*) embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the other one cannot.

Comment: The flat torus embeds into $\mathbb R^4$, just not $\mathbb R^3$